# IR not working on Attiny85

Tags: attiny, ir, isp

After countless attemps on making this thing work i'm not sure what the hell is going on. First of all you can't use the normal IR library because Attiny85 is crap and due to timer isses it wont work. So basicaly you need just the specific part which gets the data from the remote and thats all.
This is what i did but i failed badly again.

This time i used the simplest possible code which works perfectly on the Arduino UNO but it wont do anything on the Attiny85

### The code

```
int irPin     = 4;
int tipPin    = 3;
int start_bit = 2200;    //Start bit threshold (Microseconds)
int bin_1     = 1000;    //Binary 1 threshold (Microseconds)
int bin_0     = 400;     //Binary 0 threshold (Microseconds)

boolean state = 0x0;

void setup() {
   pinMode(tipPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(irPin, INPUT);
   //Serial.begin(9600);
   //Serial.println("IR/Serial Initialized: ");
}

void loop() {
   int key = getIRKey();   //Fetch the key
   //Serial.println(key);
   if (key != 0) {
     state != state;
     digitalWrite(tipPin, state);
   }
   delay(400);    // avoid double key logging (adjustable)
}

int getIRKey() {
  int data[12];
  int i;

while(pulseIn(irPin, LOW) < start_bit); //Wait for a start bit

for(i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++)
  data[i] = pulseIn(irPin, LOW);      //Start measuring bits, I only want   low pulses

  for(i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++)             //Parse them
  {
    if(data[i] > bin_1)                 //is it a 1?
data[i] = 1;
else if(data[i] > bin_0)            //is it a 0?
data[i] = 0;
else
return -1;                        //Flag the data as invalid; I don't know what it is! Return -1 on invalid data
  }

  int result = 0;
  for(i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++)             //Convert data bits to integer
    if(data[i] == 1) result |= (1<<i);

  return result;                        //Return key number
}
```

The ouput values are 3-digit numbers which work OK and i'm not even checking the value here. Just if something came in. And it doesn't bloody work!!!!

### Stuff i've already checked

- The circuit
- If the pin works
- If the timers are set correctly
- Using adafruits library
- Changing every possible core
- If the receiver works
- The wiring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to toggle the LED when a signal comes in, then there is a glitch in the code and I have no idea how the UNO worked for you as I tried and it only spat out Serial, but didn't do anything with the LED.

Try changing this line of code:

`state != state;`

**to**

`state = !state`

you are not actually toggling the LED `state` with the other line, but instead doing a logical `not equal to` which won't do what you want.

Comment: Oh my god.... Now i see it. It worked on the arduino because i wrote `state != state;` the first time then i deleted it to make it blink to test the pin and then i typed it manualy instead of pressing ctrl+z

Comment: @MeletisFlevarakis - thought it odd for a mistake like that anyway, done it myself a few times.